# jquery difference between given dates

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im trying to calculate the days between two dates but i dont want just the days difference, what i what is to write a script in order to show me all the actual dates between this 2 given dates.. 
For example i have 2 dates:

`3/12/2013` and `3/15/2013`

i want somehow to get these dates: `3/12/2013, 3/13/2013, 3/14/2013, 3/15/2013`

Here is the code ive wrote but this only return the difference in days

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var From = "03-12-2013";
  var To = "03-15-2013";
  var d1 = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("mm-dd-yy",  From);
  var d2 = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("mm-dd-yy",  To);

  var diff = 0;
  if (d1 && d2) {
      diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
  }
  console.log(diff);
});
```

thank you

Comment: I really don't know datepicker but if there is a way to substract or add one day to a date you could try to loop from one date to another, each time adding/substracting a day and saving that modified date. But after a quick look up in the API documentation I couldn't find anything like that, but maybe you know the way.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at datepicker (perhaps there is a method already giving you what you need) based on your code you could just do something like this:

```
var milisperday = 86400000,
    days = [],
    offset = (d1<d2)?d1:d2;

for (var i = 1;i<=diff;i++){
    days.push(new Date(offset.getTime() + milisperday * i));
}

console.log(days);
```

now `days` is an array containing your desired days as Date Objects.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7tQ4B/25)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.i managed to get it worked, the problem is it "thinks" that all the months have 30 days, so if i try to find the difference between 30/03/2013 and 05/04/2013 it shows me 4 days, same as the 01/04/2013 and 05/04/2013

Comment: In the jsfiddle link i get only this [] in the console

Comment: @lucky13 I guess you are using firefox... It is too dumb to parse the Date with format `mm-dd-yyyy` and only is able to use `mm/dd/yyyy`. See the updated fiddle in my answer, this should fix the issue.

Comment: oops ok i didnt saw that. again its not working ok, check it out, it stops to May 02 and not May 04

Comment: ofcourse ive already tried it. the thing that you cant understand is that not all the months have 30 days. Also give a try at your solution.. try this one http://jsfiddle.net/7tQ4B/43/  Is it working as expected?!.

Comment: I think it is not appropriate to insult the people who are helping you... Try out [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/7tQ4B/46/) and please tell my what your problem is. Are all days in the array? Is it accounting that february does not have 30 or 31 days?